# Getting total pages for every chapter in table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters

I am in need of getting total number of pages for a chapter so that in TOC it would be like 1-4 if it is chapter 1 , 5-19 for chapter 2[image]
[image: Page Numbering of Chapter start]

Comment: Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3):

The following is based on the definition of `\chapter` found in `base.sty` for book class and may not work for modified versions of \chapter.  Also, it probably conflicts with the `lastpage` package.  Oh, and you have to manually insert `\lastpage` at the end of each chapter.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\newlastpage}[2]% #1=chapter, #2=page
{\global\expandafter\def\csname lastpage@chapter#1\endcsname{#2}}

\newcommand{\thelastpage}[1]% #1 = chapter
{\@ifundefined{lastpage@chapter#1}{}%
  {\rlap{-\csname lastpage@chapter#1\endcsname}}}

\newcommand{\lastpage}%
{\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlastpage{\thechapter}{\thepage}}}

% copied (and modified) from base.sty for book class
\def\@chapter[#1]#2{\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
  \if@mainmatter
    \refstepcounter{chapter}%
    \typeout{\@chapapp\space\thechapter.}%
    \addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{\protect\numberline {\thechapter}#1}{\thepage\thelastpage{\thechapter}}}
  \else
    \addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{#1}{\thepage\thelastpage{\thechapter}}}
  \fi
\else
  \addtocontents{toc}{\contentsline {chapter}{#1}{\thepage\thelastpage{\thechapter}}}
\fi
\chaptermark{#1}%
\addtocontents{lof}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\addtocontents{lot}{\protect\addvspace{10\p@}}%
\if@twocolumn
  \@topnewpage[\@makechapterhead{#2}]%
\else
  \@makechapterhead{#2}%
\@afterheading
\fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{First}
\lipsum[1-10]
\lastpage
\chapter{Second}
\lipsum[1-10]
\lastpage

\end{document}
```