# List appendices in itemize/enumerate style

Tags: lists

I write meeting minutes once in a while, and quite often I have the need to add appendices (in the form of PDFs). I want a way to simply list all the added appendices (and their number of pages) in a simple list form like this:

```
Appendix 1: Foo (1 page)
Appendix 2: Bar (4 pages)
Appendix 3: Foobar (5 pages)
```

I know how to use use `\pdfimagex` and `\the\pdflastximagepages` to determine the number of pages in each appendix, but I am unable to produce the simple type of listing which I desire.

Can anybody help me out here, what is the most elegant/efficient way of achieve this? I have been laborating with `\tocloft` to create new "lists", however I do not want the page number reference which this introduces. Instead I want  the number of pages the appendix consist of.

Comment: Possibly related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255745/getting-total-pages-for-every-chapter-in-table-of-contents/255830?r=SearchResults&s=1|16.9006#255830

Comment: @JohnKormylo Not really. I've already figured out how to determine the number of pages in each appendix, as written in the description. My trouble is how to list the appendices in the beginning of the document when they are defined later in the same document.

Comment: The aux file is specifically used to for that purpose.  The previous version is read at \begin{document}.  If you look at your current aux file, you will probably find entries written by pdfimagex (whatever that is), not to mention toc entries.

Comment: So I know, however my knowledge in LaTeX is limited, so I do not know how to iterate over the items and only print the desired appendices. I realize that my question does not make it clear that I by "appendix" mean the external documents, I do not add them in the appendix environment provided by Latex.

Comment: Can you construct a Minimal Working Example to show what you are doing and where you want this list (minitoc) to show up?