# Create Statistics from table of contents

Tags: tikz-pgf, table-of-contents

I'm writing a thesis about dashboards and visualization for science communication. I thought it would be a neat trick to show a pie chart at the beginning of every chapter to present how big the section is. For example: if there is a chapter x in which the section 1 has 10 pages, the section 2 has 6 pages and the section 3 has 4 pages, then there would be a pie chart in which section 1 is 50%, section 2 is 30% and section 3 is 20%.

Would it be possible to read out the page numbers for each section, calculate the net pages, and create a pie chart with tikz?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It should be possible, but you would need to store the page number in some auxiliary file and compile several times, because the page number can only be known after the document has been typeset at least once (or maybe twice).

Comment: Thank you. I don't think this is an obstacle because it compiles multiple times. How do I read out values from auxiliary?

Comment: The aux file consists of executable TeX commands.  The TOC uses `\@writefile{toc}{\contentsline ...}` to put executables into the toc file.  Long story short ("too late!") you either need to modify `\contentsline` to save the arguments into global macros (using `\csname`) for later analysis, or write your own commands (using `\string`) to the aux file.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/255745/getting-total-pages-for-every-chapter-in-table-of-contents

Answer (score 4):

The answer below uses the [wheelchart](https://ctan.org/pkg/wheelchart) package, which I wrote.

To compute the number of pages, the package [totalcount](https://ctan.org/pkg/totalcount) is used.

The package [etoc](https://ctan.org/pkg/etoc) is required to create this table of contents.

The `tikzpicture` environment is placed inside `\iftotalpages` ... `\fi` such that this is only executed if `\totalpages` is known. This value is given to the key `etoc count total pages`.

The macro `\WCetocthename` corresponds to `\etocthename`.

The gaps between the arcs are obtained with the keys `gap` and `gap radius`.

The key `value` is defined by `\WCetocthenumberofpages`, which corresponds to the number of pages of the current (sub)section.

The key `etoc level` determines the level of the table of contents.

The colors are determined with a list using the key `slices style{list}`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[page]{totalcount}
\usepackage{wheelchart}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
\usepackage{etoc}
\etocsettocstyle{\hypersetup{hidelinks}}{}
\etocglobaldefs
\usepackage[linktoc=all,pdfstartview=FitH,colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\iftotalpages\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfkeys{
  /wheelchart,
  arc data=\WCetocthename,
  arc data pos=0.5,
  etoc count total pages=\totalpages,
  gap,
  gap radius,
  value=\WCetocthenumberofpages
}
\wheelchart[
  data=,
  etoc level=subsection,
  middle={\Huge Title},
  slices style{list}={orange!50,orange!75,green!20,green!40,green!60,green!80,purple!25,purple!50,purple!75}
]{}
\wheelchart[
  data=\WCetocthelinkedname\\\WCetocthelinkednumber\\page \WCetocthelinkedpage,
  etoc level=section,
  radius={3}{4},
  slices style{list}={orange,green,purple}
]{}
\end{tikzpicture}\fi
\section{Section A}
\subsection{A.1}
\newpage
\subsection{A.2}
\newpage
\section{Section B}
\subsection{B.1}
\newpage
\subsection{B.2}
\newpage
\subsection{B.3}
\newpage
\subsection{B.4}
\newpage
\section{Section C}
\subsection{C.1}
\newpage
\subsection{C.2}
\newpage
\subsection{C.3}
\end{document}
```

The figure below is from the package documentation.

[image]

Comment: neat TOCs there!

Comment: I deleted an earlier comment as I had not yet understood that `etoc` use is via your neat package... I guess you can adapt your answer to do one such TOCchart per chapter?

Comment: @user691586 Thank you! This method requires the package `etoc`. The `wheelchart` package provides the key `etoc code`, which is initially `\tableofcontents`. The way how the table of contents is processed (such as one table of contents per chapter) can be further configured with the methods from the package `etoc`.